# Unable to assign text back to Form TextBox Control in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code i am using in Excel Code Behind, I am getting the following error "run time error 1004 unable to set the text property of the characters class". "txtXmlString" is the name of my textbox control used in Excel Sheet, External FPrm is my Sheet Name.

```
Private Sub CreateXMLString()

    sf = "testdata"

    Worksheets("External form").Shapes("txtXmlString").TextFrame.Characters.Text = sf

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not a shape I think, it's an ActiveX control? How did you add the textbox from Excel?

Comment: I dont want to use ActiveX textBox Control as i have some complications related to that ActiveX Control , i went inside Insert tab - Text-and from there i selected TextBox

Answer (score 0):

If you've added a textbox control in an Excel sheet, it's an ActiveX Control. That being said, select it to get its name (should be `Textbox1` or 2 if you have many by default). Once you got its name, you can set its text property as follow:

```
Sub Test()
Worksheets("External form").TextBox1.Value = "testdata"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to my issue , here is is the code

Private Sub CreateXMLString()

Dim sf As String
    sf = "testdata"
    Worksheets("External form").Shapes("txtXmlString").TextFrame.Characters.Text = sf

End Sub

Note : need to change the property of Textbox control to Unlocked & UnlockedText